# How to pass the name of the html form / filename to python - CGI / HTML / Python

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have searched a bunch on the net and StackOverflow and still haven't figured the answer.

I have two HTML forms something.html (for users) and something_test.html (for co-developers), both passing the inputs in the forms to the same python script using POST. My question is how do I know in the python script, which HTML form sent the inputs? In my case, if it is 'something_test.html', then the displayed output will be much more verbose.

Is the form-name stored in some variable that I can parse in the python script.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your forms should be POSTing to a specific route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assuming you are already able to parse the form data...

I would just add a hidden input field to your forms like so:

### something.html

```
<input type="hidden" id="formName" name="name_of_form" value="something">
```

### something_test.html

```
<input type="hidden" id="formName" name="name_of_form" value="something_test">
```

Then when processing the form data in your python script, the name of the forms will be available in "name_of_form".